# pasting truncates text lines into an emacs buffer

Tags: emacs

I copied more than 100 lines of text and pasted it into emacs (`23.1.1`), but only the first 50 lines or so actually get pasted.

Is there a setting somewhere that I can poke to increase the size?

Comment: X? What does `xsel -b | wc -c` give you?

Comment: Errr, sorry, English would be appreciated, as I have no idea what the command you just typed does.

Comment: Are you using X? (Unix?) `xsel -b | wc -c` counts the number of characters on the clipboard.

Comment: @minitech is trying to see if it's a problem with Emacs, or a problem with your OS/desktop environment. If you're on Linux, that command takes the contents of the keyboard (`xsel -b`), and then counts the number of bytes (`wc -c`). Actually, `wc -l` is probably more useful, because that counts the number of lines, not the number of bytes. Alternately, you could open up a text editor, and paste your clipboard in there. That way you can see if the problem is Emacs or the problem is your OS.

Comment: Ah, ok (you could've just asked for the info, rather than giving the mean to get it). Anyway, there're about 80 (chars per line) * 100 (lines).

Comment: No, I couldn’t have, because I’m trying to determine whether what you’re copying is getting chopped off. You need both numbers.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC when inserting, the number of lines doesn't matter. Emacs inserts just numbers, which represent characters. The character "\n" is one of them maybe. After insertion, Emacs reads these numbers, i.e. displays a representation of these numbers as characters.

The only limitation here is the maximal amount of numbers/chars a buffer may hold. With around 80 chars in each 100 lines you are an eternity below. Assume it's just a copy error/mistake.